# Read a Lagre File into stream In time Intervals

Tags: c#, file, time

I want to read a text/audio file to a stream in particular time interval say 10sec.

I have a audio file, which i want to read to a stream. Say the file have data 1 to 100. First it will read the file(1 to 10) in 10 sec & pass it to stream object. In next 10 sec it will read (11 to 20)  and again write it to the strem & so on.

Does any one have the example or code for ref.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose there are numerous open source projects for you to look at for ideas.

Mind the license;

e.g.

- [banshee](http://banshee-project.org/Main_Page),
- [muine](http://muine.gooeylinux.org/), all using GStreamer

Comment: can u suggest any code for ref to do that as i am not  getting u?

Comment: You ask a very broad question. Unfortunately I don't have the time to do the reading, searching and coding for <strike>u</strike>you

Comment: [banshee](http://git.gnome.org/browse/banshee/tree/src), [muine](http://git.gnome.org/browse/muine/tree/)